# Run task when a new branch was created

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo

im new to the ci/cd topic. We are decided to move to  Jira, Bitbucket and Bamboo.

I think I didn't fully understand concept of bamboo.

We're using the following branches

- `develop` as our development branch,
- `master` for our regular releases. (e.g. 4.2, 4.5, 5, 5.1) => Major.Minor
- `release/` for hotfixes and security fixes for older major version (if the major version is already at 5 und we have to fix a bug in 4.xx
- `feature/`

On a push our development instance will be updated automatically. 
We also already have a script for cloning, creating the instance, setup apache etc...

Now I want that a the script will run every time a new `feature/`was created, but I didn't found a solution for that.

It's possible to run a task in bamboo on branch creation?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already created a plan, you need to do that as step one. Plans can run every time you create a branch or make a commit.
Under plan configuration -> Branches tab -> Create plan branch section, you can specify; "When new branch in repository is created and matches expression" and use e.g. "feature/.+" as expression.
Next add a stage. Stages can have one or more tasks. There is a dedicated script task that can run both Unix and Windows commands depending on what build agent you are using. 
To sum it all up; a plan can have one or more stages, which can have one or more tasks.

It's also possible to make webhooks from bitbucket that can trigger on different parameters, like branch update and pull requests etc.